# Group SQL data and split into columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following columns, where the timestamp column indicates the date the user viewed a product, and the purchase column if the view generated a purchase:

| id | userId | productId | timestamp | purchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2022-01-07 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 2022-01-10 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 4 | 2022-01-12 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 | 2022-01-16 | 1 |

How to group the data by userId and productId in order to return as follows:

| id | userId | productId | firstView | lastView | firstPurchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-01-16 | 2022-01-10 |

For the firstView and listView columns I know I should use Min() and Max(), but the firstPurchase column I can't display. I tried using `CASE` when column purchase = 1 but it didn't work.

Comment: And your code is where ? Show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `MIN(CASE WHEN purchase = 1 THEN "timestamp" ELSE NULL END)`, like this:

```
create table your_table (id int, userId int, productId int, "timestamp" date, purchase int)

insert into your_table (id, userId, productId, "timestamp", purchase)
values
(1,2,4,'2022-01-07 00:00:00',0),
(2,2,4,'2022-01-10 00:00:00',1),
(3,2,4,'2022-01-12 00:00:00',0),
(4,2,4,'2022-01-16 00:00:00',1);


SELECT  
       userId, 
       productId, 
       MIN(timestamp) AS firstView, 
       MAX(timestamp) AS lastView, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN purchase = 1 THEN "timestamp" ELSE NULL END) AS firstPurchase
FROM your_table
GROUP BY 
         userId,
         productId;
```

p.s. please don't call a column "timestamp" :)

Comment: I understood. I wasn't using END in the CASE.

About the "timestamp" was just for example, it's not the correct name. Thanks!

Comment: Hi dear, I've written without GROUP BY because in the field list wht OP has added the id column. Without that column your query is the best

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.userId, t1.productId, t1.timestamp,
(SELECT t3.timestamp
FROM yourtable t3
WHERE t3.userId = t1.userId
AND t3.productId = t1.productId
AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
    FROM yourtable t4
    WHERE t4.userId = t3.userId
    AND t4.productId = t3.productId
    AND t4.timestamp > t3.timestamp
    )
) as lastView,
(SELECT t3.timestamp
FROM yourtable t3
WHERE t3.userId = t1.userId
AND t3.productId = t1.productId
AND t3.purchase = 1
AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
    FROM yourtable t4
    WHERE t4.userId = t3.userId
    AND t4.productId = t3.productId
    AND t4.timestamp < t3.timestamp
    AND t4.purchase = 1
    )
) as firstPurchase
FROM yourtable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM yourtable t2
    WHERE t1.userId = t2.userId
    AND t1.productId = t2.productId
    AND t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp)
```

See [**Sql Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/817f00/2/0)